# Data won't display on my MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, html-table

I'm creating an MVC website for college and I'm attempting to display data from a DropCreateDatabase which I have entered fields for with a DbInitialiser. I have attempted to use the debugger to solve this problem but I can't work it out.

Here is a part of my DBInitialiser:

```
//override
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            // CUSTOMERS
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Customer"))
            {
                var role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Customer";
                roleManager.Create(role);

                string username = "customer1@customer1.com";
                string password = "123456";

                var user = userManager.FindByName(username);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    var newCustomer = new User()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Philip",
                        LastName = "Fry",
                        Town = "Old New York City",
                        Role = "Customer",
                        Email = username,
                        UserName = username,
                        EmailConfirmed = true
                    };
                    userManager.Create(newCustomer, password);
                    userManager.AddToRole(newCustomer.Id, "Customer");
                }
context.SaveChanges();

            //add types of announcements
            context.AnnouncementTypes.Add(
                new AnnouncementType { TypeName = "Movie Review" }
                );

context.SaveChanges();

context.Announcements.Add(
                new Announcement
                {
                    //using FirstOrDefault to make sure it doesn't crash if there is 0
                    //link statement to look for "Movie Review" and return the ProductTypeid
                    AnnouncementType = context.AnnouncementTypes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.TypeName == "Movie Review"),
                    AnnouncementTitle = "Back To The Future Part 4",
                    Description = "A lot better than the 6th one"
                }
                );

base.Seed(context);
```

This is the part of the controller that is being called:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

// GET: Announcements
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var announcements = db.Announcements.Include(a => a.AnnouncementType);
    return View(announcements.ToList());
}
```

This is the view, the problem seems to be here:

```
@model IEnumerable<Theatre.Models.Announcement>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnnouncementType.TypeName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnnouncementTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnnouncementType.TypeName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnnouncementTitle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AnnouncementId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AnnouncementId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AnnouncementId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The foreach loop doesn't get run, I think it's because Model is empty but I don't know how. I based this code similar to another project I did for college and it works fine on that.

Comment: There are more roles, users, announcement types and announcements but I only showed one of each so that the question wasn't too full of code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't calling context.SaveChanges() after adding the Announcement.

Comment: just tried adding that but it didn't change anything